# write from one file to another

Tags: python, file-handling

1. Takes `secret_msg` and path as parameters

   2. Opens the file mentioned in the path in a+ mode
   3. Writes the content of the `secret_msg` in the above opened file. How do I do this ? it says error

> 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
>    4. Closes the file

Returns:
The function has no return parameters

```
message_parts=[secret_msg_3, secret_msg_1, secret_msg_4, secret_msg_2]
final_path= user_data_dir + '/secret_message.txt'

#Code starts here
secret_msg = " ".join(message_parts)
def write_file(secret_msg, path) :
    open("path" , 'a+' )
    path.write(secret_msg)
    path.close()

write_file(secret_msg,final_path)

print(secret_msg)
```

Comment: So what is the question ?

Comment: im getting an error

Comment: HOW DO I write the content of the secret_path into path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) the file and then call the `write` method.

Here one way:

```
def write_file(secret_msg, path):
    f = open(path, 'a+')
    f.write(secret_msg)
    f.close()
```

or using `with`:

```
def write_file(secret_msg, path):
    with open(path, 'a+') as f:
        f.write(secret_msg)
```

I advice you to have a look at [How to write a file with Python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp).

Hope that help !

Comment: Glad to help you ! Happy coding !